# Unlock lg ls777

Tags: lg, sim-unlocking, lg-g-stylo

I have a boost mobile lg stylo 3 that i want to unlock to use on the T-Mobile network. What are the steps to unlock it from boost to be usable on another network?

Answer (score 0):

It's usually a simple call to your mobile service provider... On Optus it was free, however I'm not sure anymore, many providers ask for a fee to unlock the handset, usually under $100 AUD in Australia, Around $80 in my experience...

1. Ring your provider
2. Request a Service Unlock ( Provider Unlock ) 
   I can't remember the name, just explain that you would like to use another provider's SIM card, they'll know what you mean.
3. They'll ask for you to pay a fee ( if required by the provider )
4. You usually call a specific number, and enter the code they give you ... The method may have changed but your provider will identify the needed steps on your specific device..

Usually the unlock code is unique to the IMEI number of your device, so be prepared and get everything ready... You can grab the IMEI number ( usually the first step ) by calling *#06#